# Managing multiple positions in Pinescript (i.e. adding/reducing volume when in loss/profit)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Regardless of what our strategy might be, I was trying to make **two entry points** when my "longCondition" is met.
First, I open a position half the amount of my equity in the first entry level, then the other half in midway between entry level and SL level.

```
//@version=5
strategy("TWO ENTRY STRATEGY", overlay=true, initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_value = 10, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
GetPipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)
pipSize = GetPipSize()

var entryVolume = 50 // the percentage of my equity used for first entry level
var middleTpVolume = -50 // reduce half the size of all open positions in midway between entry level and TP level.
var middleSlVolume = 50 // add the other half of the equity in.
entry = close
stopLoss = close - (20 * pipSize)
takeProfit = close + (20 * pipSize)
SlEntryDiff = math.abs(entry - stopLoss)
positionSizeA = entryVolume * (strategy.equity / SlEntryDiff) / 100
positionSizeB = middleSlVolume * (strategy.equity / SlEntryDiff) / 100

if (longCondition and strategy.opentrades == 0)
    strategy.entry("longA", strategy.long, qty = positionSizeA)
    // exit half of the volume in midway between entry level and TP level
    strategy.exit("exitLongA_1", from_entry = "longA", qty_percent = math.abs(middleTpVolume / 100) * positionSizeA, limit = middleTp, comment_profit = "Middle TP.A")
    // close all remaining volume of the position on SL or TP level (to whichever reached first.)
    strategy.exit("exitLongA_2", from_entry = "longA", qty_percent = 100, limit = takeProfit, stop = stopLoss, comment_profit = "TP.A", comment_loss = "SL.A")
    // manage second entry
    strategy.entry("longB", strategy.long, qty = positionSizeB, limit = middleSl)
    strategy.exit("exitLongB", from_entry = "longB", qty_percent = math.abs(middleTpVolume / 100) * positionSizeB, limit = middleTp, comment_profit = "middle TP.B")
    // close all remaining volume of the position on SL or TP level (to whichever reached first.)
    strategy.exit("exitLongB", from_entry = "longB", qty_percent = 100, limit = takeProfit, stop = stopLoss, comment_profit = "TP.B", comment_loss = "SL.B")
```

my problems are as follows:

1- Assume my first entry is filled and goes straight to the tp level (without filling the second entry (i.e. longB)), so now "longB" should be cancelled. how could I cancel "longB"? I'm looking for  something like this:

```
if close >= takeProfit
    strategy.cancel("longB")
```

but this is not the solution for me.

2- I want to risk 10% of my equity on each trade. How can I achieve this?